# Wilfdly not picking up mysql hibernate configuration in persistence.xml

Tags: mysql, hibernate, wildfly, persistence.xml

i'm having difficulty get Wildfly to use MySQL as a database, no connections are made. I have the following in the persistence.xml file:

```
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="primary">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/X" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="X" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="X" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />

            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Changing e.g the dialect shows up in the logfiles, changing the persistence-unit name also affects the application so the persistence.xml is picked up except for the mysql part.

Any help appreciated,

-- 
Michel

Comment: It would be a better practice to use a application server managed connection pool in your case.

Comment: @Quincy Thanks for the suggestion but moving to a managed setup i have exactly the same problem.